# How to use dynamic ldap config options in a Nestjs app using passport-ldapauth library?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ldap, passport.js, nestjs

I am trying to authenticate against active directory using passport-ldapauth in a Nestjs app.  I don't have a service account and want to bind to Active Directory using a username as DN.  I am trying to use the Asynchronous configuration retrieval but running into a problem when calling super() in the strategy class's constructor.

I get the following error:

src/ldap.strategy.ts:12:9 - error TS17009: 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class.
12      super(this.getLdapConfig,

Any idea how I can make this work in a Nestjs app by extending the strategy interface/passing dynamic config method when calling super()?

my code:

```
import * as Strategy from 'passport-ldapauth';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { callbackify } from 'util';

@Injectable()
export class LdapStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'ldap') {
    constructor(
    ) {     
        super(this.getLdapConfig,
         async (req: Request, user: any, done) => {
            console.log(req);
            req.user = user;
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }

    getLdapConfig(req: Request, callback: any) {
        
        process.nextTick(() => {
        let opts = {
            passReqToCallback: true,
            server: {
                url: 'ldaps://eassec.cc.corp:636',
                bindDN: `CN=${req.username}`,
                bindCredentials: '${req.password}',
                tlsOptions: {
                    ca: [
                        readFileSync('./src/public.crt')
                    ],
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                },
                searchBase: 'ou=BU-IT',
                searchFilter: `(&(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))(sAMAccountName=${req.username}))`
                searchAttributes: ['displayName', 'mail'],
            }

        };

            callback(null, opts);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried extracting `getLdapConfig` to a const or function declared outside this class and then passing it into `super`? I don't see any reason why it needs to be a class method

Comment: @Jesse Carter thanks that worked, stupid mistake...  Please add this as the answer.

Comment: Nice! Glad that it helped out. It's an easy mistake to make I do screw up on stuff like this all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just extract `getLdapConfig` to a const (arrow function) or regular function declared outside the class and then pass it into the `super` call.

It doesn't reference any class members itself so there's no reason that it needs to be a class method.